# Time reversal symmetry and electromagnetic response

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, many-body

Dynamics polarizability of a quantum system in the random phase approximation can be calculated as
$$
\Pi_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}',\omega)=\sum_{ij}\varphi^*_i(\mathbf{r})\varphi_j(\mathbf{r})\varphi_i(\mathbf{r}')\varphi_j^*(\mathbf{r}')\frac{f_i-f_j}{\omega+\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j},
$$
where $\epsilon_i$ and $\varphi_i(\mathbf{r})$ are single-particle energies and wave functions, $f_i=1,0$ for occupied and unoccupied states.

After rearranging the terms we have
$$
\Pi_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}',\omega)=\sum_{ij}\frac{i\omega(f_i-f_j)\mathrm{Im}\,[\varphi^*_i(\mathbf{r})\varphi_j(\mathbf{r})\varphi_i(\mathbf{r}')\varphi_j^*(\mathbf{r}')]+(f_i-f_j)(\epsilon_j-\epsilon_i)\mathrm{Re}\,[\varphi^*_i(\mathbf{r})\varphi_j(\mathbf{r})\varphi_i(\mathbf{r}')\varphi_j^*(\mathbf{r}')]}{\omega^2-(\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j)^2}.
$$
We can note the imaginary part of $\Pi_0$ is odd in $\omega$ while the real part is even, i.e. $\Pi_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}',\omega)^*=\Pi_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}',-\omega)$.

It is known that **in the time reversal invariant system** all single-particle wave functions $\varphi_i(\mathbf{r})$ can be chosen to be real, thus $\mathrm{Im}\,\Pi_0=0$ and $\mathrm{Re}\,\Pi_0$ depends only on $\omega^2$. This means the electromagnetic response arises always **in phase** with an external field.

**1) How to understand it on physical grounds?**

**2) Does this in-phase response imply absence of electromagnetic absorption? Why?**

3) If $\Pi_0$ is even function of $\omega$ in the presence of time reversal symmetry and is not in the absence of it, how it is reflected in plasmons described by the equation $1-V\Pi_0=0$? Recently I had the related question in this issue: [How to derive Casida equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345380/how-to-derive-casida-equation)